# How to modify default category widget list display?

Tags: categories

I am using default category widget in blogs posts page in sidebar. I am able to display categories with count but the view is not looks good. I want to know the file which is having the list . I am unable to find this file.Please anybody let me know what is the file location?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the appearance, try editing the css that targets the categories.

If you want to change the text "Filled under:" (`before`) or the "," (`sep`) that separate the categories, in my Genesis theme I use the following code . Try adapting it by changing `genesis_post_meta` to your version.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'sp_post_meta' );
function sp_post_meta( $post_meta ) {
    $post_meta = '[post_category before="" sep=""]';
    return $post_meta;
}
```